# Do all vectors have direction and magnitude?

Tags: vector-spaces, intuition

[image: Vector -- Despicable Me]

> I go by [Vector](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1323594/). It's a mathematical term, represented by an arrow with both direction and magnitude. Vector! That's me, because I commit crimes with both direction and magnitude. Oh yeah!

For [Euclidean vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector), it's natural to think of vectors having direction and magnitude.  What about vectors in abstract [vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)?  Is it possible to (sensibly) define notions of direction and magnitude for all vectors?

(If not, what is an example which highlights why it's not always possible?)

Comment: The vector itself describes the direction. To have a notion of magnitude you need a norm.

Comment: (1,2,3,4) is a vector, can you find it's direction?

Comment: Hmm... I suppose I'd describe its direction using a unit vector: basically, the direction would be $(1,2,3,4)/||(1,2,3,4)||$.  This way, e.g. $(2,4,6,8)$ would have the same direction.

Comment: @Rebecca That's defining the direction of $(1,2,3,4)$ by the direction of its 'normalization'. But you still need to define direction for $(1,2,3,4)/\left\Vert (1,2,3,4)\right\Vert$.

Comment: @Vikram How would you define direction for a vector in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2$ one can define direction of a vector $(a,b) $ by the angle between $(a,b)$ and $(1,0)$, for instance. Not sure how to generalize this to $\Bbb R^3$, but if it is doable, then it's probably doable for any dimension.

Comment: In that case, it might be best to generalise it to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by using a $\binom{n}{2}$-tuple of angles, one for each plane spanned by vectors along a pair of coordinate axes.  The angles wouldn't be independent; in fact, it should have $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: vectors in linear algebra are collection of mathematical objects(not always real numbers), so the notion of direction in the  traditional sense(or in any other sense!) in finding the angle between x, y, z axis does not apply (I have just started LA, but this is my understanding)

Comment: @Vikram That's seems so. But maybe there's a good definition of direction that doesn't have anything to do with angles or axis.

Comment: I just want to add something to the discussion about degrees of freedom and parametrization. The 1-dimensional [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) or the [projective space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) is the set of one-dimensional subspaces, and I think this corresponds exactly to the set of directions. If the underlying vector space has a topology, the projective space inherits the quotient topology.

Comment: It should be noted in addition that few vectors, if any, have piranha-guns. Or squid-launchers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Summary

There's a reasonable definition of direction in abstract vector spaces, but that doesn't always include "orientation." To talk about magnitudes *as lengths*, you really need extra structure provided by a norm into an ordered field.

### Direction

In abstract vector spaces, you can link a weak idea of "direction" with a vector directly by just defining:

> We say $v$ and $w$ *have the same direction* if $\langle v\rangle=\langle w\rangle$. ($\langle\dots \rangle$ is denoting linear span, here.)

That is, each $1$-dimensional subspace could be thought of as a class of vectors in the same direction. Notice, though, that this scheme has you think of the zero vector as being "in all directions," and maybe philosophically then it has no direction at all :)

Some folks might also include a component of *[orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28vector_space%29)* when they're thinking about "direction," so we should discuss that too. As far as I can tell, this necessitates $F$ to be an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) $F$ so that you can establish a dichotomy of what is positive and what is negative. (You don't *have* to have orientation if you're happy with the definition of direction above, but I think it's worth discussing.)

Given a direction $\langle v \rangle$ (and an ordering on your field of course), one could say that the elements of $A=\{\lambda v\mid \lambda>0\}$ are mutually oriented in the same way, and $B=\{\lambda v\mid \lambda<0\}$ as oriented in "the other" way, and they are oriented oppositely to those things in $A$. This is a problem for finite fields, which can't be ordered. In [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29) $2$ fields, for example, $v=-v$ for all vectors, so the dichotomy doesn't exist at all, there.

### Magnitude

To talk about *lengths* in an abstract vetor space, you really need an extra structure called a *[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space)*. This gives you a way to measure how "long" vectors are. Being able to compare lengths of vectors with a norm again only makes sense when you are working with a norm into an ordered field, so that you can distinguish which magnitude is greater.

On the other hand, if you're just happy to have some sort of scalar for each vector, then there are generalizations of norms into nonordered fields that would work. You just couldn't interpret their values as lengths. Really, our geometric intuition about length is all bound up in ordered fields.

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: I'll delete my answer, this one answers it much more completely.

Comment: I like your definition that two vectors are in the same direction if they generate the same subspace.  A further question:  if there is an inner product on the space, can that be used to define a direction?  It clearly can in the finite dimensional vector spaces, but whatg about a more general space?

Comment: Dear @StefanSmith : Please consider rereading what I've said there about direction and orientation. The example you gave does not contradict anything I've said. $\langle w \rangle=\langle -v\rangle=\langle v\rangle$ are all part of the same direction. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about formally real fields. From the wiki it looks like they are just fields where the naive dot product is positive definite, and apparently that is sufficient for the field to be ordered. Regards.

Comment: Dear @BettyMock :Thanks, glad it's useful! Do you mean "if you have an inner product, can you define a *magnitude*"? (The direction could be defined in any case in the way above.) Sure, if you have a positive definite inner product $\langle\cdot\mid \cdot\rangle$ into an ordered field, then you get a norm for free with $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x\mid x\rangle}$. Oop, I guess that means we would also have to require square roots for all positive elements. Notice that vectors "in the same direction" would be all parallel to each other, and this is equivalent to being in the same $1$-d subspace.

Comment: Dear @StefanSmith If you had read it carefully, you'd see that I wrote that it is a *weak idea of direction* and in following paragraphs I predicted and addressed the objection about orientation. The two sets described in the orientation paragraph seem to be exactly what you're proposing. I don't mind explaining the span notation, so I'll do that. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb I liked the idea that all elements of a given 1 dim space could be considered in the same "direction". Re + and -  a 1-dim space would include both if the underlying field is ordered. (continued -- I'm a few characters over )

Comment: @rschwieb Re an inner product producing a magnitude, it didn't occur to me; I figured if you have a norm you have a magnitude; & assumed not every inner product would  generate a norm, which you demonstrate. In finite dim spaces the inner product does define the angle between two vectors, so I was wondering if that idea can be generalized.  I was thinking that in an inner product space there is a concept of orthogonality , so why not other angles.

Comment: @BettyMock The study of real [Hilbert spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) takes inner products to infinite dimensional spaces, so you might ask around about Hilbert spaces. I'm not sure what's being asked in the last sentence though: could you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: @rschweib : sorry if I didn't read carefully enough.  \thank you for your time.

Comment: @rschwieb -- I'm aware of Hilbert spaces and their inner products.  What I was asking is,since the inner product does define and angle and hence direction (at least with respect to a set of basis vectors) in finite dimensional spaces, might it do so also where the space is not finite? dimensional?  I can certainly look if there is anything about this re Hilbert spaces; if no that answers the question; and if yes it would be a start to considering more general spaces.  But if you happen to know the answer ...

Comment: @BettyMock Whatever real inner product you have (infinite dimensional space or not) you can define $\theta=\arccos(\frac{\langle a\mid b\rangle}{\|a\|\|b\|})$, so the dimension does not seem to come into play.

Comment: I didn't know whether the dimension had anything to do with it.  But now that I think about it, it doesn't seem very useful.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BettyMock You're very welcome! :)